# How to very SIMPLY deploy a Twisted Server on OPenshift

Tags: python, twisted, openshift

I've got the right environment setup, python 2.7.5, Twisted installed and imports work in the Python Shell.

I have a very simple Server instance to display a landing page that Works on local machine fine.

```
from twisted.web import http

class MyRequestHandler(http.Request):
    pages={
    '/': '<h1>Geo-Address Server</h1>Twisted Server is Up and Running..',
    '/test': '<h1>Test</h1>Test page',
    }
    def process(self):
        print self.path
        if self.pages.has_key(self.path):
            self.write(self.pages[self.path])
        else:
            self.setResponseCode(http.NOT_FOUND)
            self.write("<h1>Not Found</h1>Sorry, page does not exist")
        self.finish()

class MyHttp(http.HTTPChannel):
    requestFactory=MyRequestHandler

class MyHttpFactory(http.HTTPFactory):
    protocol=MyHttp

if __name__=='__main__':
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    reactor.listenTCP(8080, MyHttpFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

However, deploying this on the Openshift Server fails to run. If I try to run the script

```
python script.py &
```

I get:

> reactor.listenTCP(8080, MyHttpFactory())   File
>   "/var/lib/openshift/5378ea844382ec89da000432/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py",
>   line 495, in listenTCP
>       p.startListening()   File "/var/lib/openshift/5378ea844382ec89da000432/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py",
>   line 979, in startListening
>       raise CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le) twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:8080:
>   [Errno 13] Permission denied.

Reading through SO, most people just say to bind to port 8080(which I have done), but still I get the same error.

Comment: See [this KB article](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1038-i-cant-bind-to-a-port) and [this thread](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/basic-python-program-with-socketerror-errno-13-permission-denied-error). OpenShift apparently doesn't allow you to bind to arbitrary (even unprivileged) ports on the external interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [kb](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1038-i-cant-bind-to-a-port) says

> Please note: We don't allow arbitrary binding of ports on the
>   externally accessible IP address.
>
> It is possible to bind to the internal IP with port range: 15000 -
>   35530. All other ports are reserved for specific processes to avoid conflicts. Since we're binding to the internal IP, you will need to
>   use port forwarding to access it:
>   https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift

Therefor, just find out the $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP

```
echo $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP
```

Then add that address to the reactor listener's interface

```
reactor.listenTCP(15000, MyHttpFactory(), interface='127.X.X.X')
```

Alternative(and the best) way to do it is by picking the value in the code. That way, if the IP changes dynamically, you still get the current IP

```
import os

local_hostname =os.getenv("OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP")
..
..
reactor.listenTCP(15000, MyHttpFactory(), interface=local_hostname)
```

*Note: You can only bind to the port range (15000-35530)*